# Relationship between the semantics of simply typed lambda calculus and combinatory logic

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, combinatory-logic

The simply typed lambda calculus has a class of extremely intuitive models where each basic type $\sigma$ is modeled by some set $[\![\sigma]\!]$, and a complex type $\sigma\rightarrow\tau$ is then straightforwardly interpreted as the full function space $[\![\tau]\!]^{[\![\sigma]\!]}$.

It seems like simply typed combinatory logic should have models of exactly the same kind, with each basic combinator getting a fixed uniform interpretation so that it picks out the 'right' object of its type.

It's also well known how to emulate abstraction in combinatory logic, by defining a term $[x].M$ that behaves like $\lambda x. M$ in the sense that $([x].M\ N)\vartriangleright M[N/x]$.

My question is whether or not there is a strong semantic correspondence between $[x].M$ and $\lambda x. M$ in the kind of extremely simple models that I gestured out. I would guess that $[ \! [[x].M]\! ]=[\![ \lambda x. M]\!]$, but I haven't been able to find an explicit discussion of this anywhere.

Comment: $[x].M$ is not a CL term, in the sense that it e.g. conflicts with the definition of substitution in CL terms. $[x].M$ is just a meta-linguistic operation, a notation for a preliminary translation state that will be eliminated in the further process of converting a $\lambda$ term into a CL term. So if one wanted to assign an interpretation to $[x].M$ in order to establish an equilvalence to $\lambda x.M$, one would need to extend the semantics outside actual CL-terms to also include the metatheoretic operation of $[x].M$.

Comment: I'm aware that $[x].M$ is just a meta-linguistic shorthand for the result of a certain substitution. I'm not sure I follow why we would need to extend the semantics to prove anything about how it gets interpreted, though -- why isn't $[\![[].]\!]$ likewise just meta-linguistic shorthand for whatever object is assigned to the result of carrying out the translation?

Comment: Of course, we could define $[[...]]$ in such a way that the meta-linguistic operation $[x].M$ is included. I just wanted to point out that this is not immediately obvious, as the first natural thought would be that defining a semantics on CL amounts to a semantics simply on the CL terms, which wouldn't include the $[x].M$ construct.

Comment: "[]. that behaves like . in the sense that ([]. )⊳[/]" how do you define substitution on combinatory terms (which contain no variables)?

Comment: Combinatory terms don't have _bound_ variables -- M may contain a free $x$, and so substitution can be defined totally normally (and without the hassle of having to worry about accidental capture). Of course, as was noted above $[x].M$ is just a metalinguistic abbreviation for a combinatory term that $x$ does not really appear in (and so $M$ isn't really a proper syntactic constituent of $[x].M$).